# MVVM Light Code snpipet not appearing after update in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, code-snippets

After updating to latest version 5.0.2.0 of MVVM light code snipets are not showing for all MVVM light operation in my visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating MVVM Light to latest version 5.0.2.0. installer removes the previous folder of code snippets and adds new folder for it. To fix this issue open **Tools-> Code snippet Manager**

Select **Visual C#** in Language and click Add

go to your code snippet folder. e.g *C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions* open **hjcywkk3.v4k** and select **MvvmLightCSharpSnippets** folder for C# code snippets

Hope this helps